# C : find and remove a member of a struct of structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have two structs declared in this way:

```
struct record {
  const char *entry;
  struct record *next;
};

struct s_table {
  int capacity;
  struct record *records;
};
```

And I wrote a method to remove a member of the struct s_table:

```
int s_table_remove_record(struct s_table *t, const char *begin,
                          const char *end) {

  if (!t) {
    printf("No table");
    return 0;
  }

  printf("inside remove_record \n");
  if (strcmp(begin, t->records->entry) == 0) {
    printf("record found in the first if.");

    struct record *temp = t->records->next;
    free(t);
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Before allocating the head\n");

  struct record *head = t->records;

  for (; t->records->next; t->records = t->records->next) {
    printf("Inside the for loop \n");

    if (strcmp(begin, t->records->entry) == 0) {
      printf("record found in the second if");

      struct record *temp = t->records->next;
      t->records->next = t->records->next->next;
      free(temp);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  printf("record not found\n");

  return 0;
}
```

However I never get inside the for loop. Could you help me understand why and provide a solution?

To test the code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct record {
  const char *entry;
  struct record *next;
};

struct s_table {
  int capacity;
  struct record *records;
};

static int counter = 0;

struct s_table *s_table_new() {
  struct s_table *t = (struct s_table *)malloc(sizeof(t));
  t->capacity = 1000;
  t->records = (struct record *)malloc(sizeof(struct record) * t->capacity);

  return t;
}

int s_table_add_record(struct s_table *t, const char *begin, const char *end) {

  if (!t) {
    printf("No table");
    return 0;
  }

  if (counter > t->capacity) {
    printf("Not enough space!");
    return 0;
  }

  t->records[counter].entry = begin;
  printf("Record add is: %s \n", t->records[counter].entry);

  if (!t) {
    printf("Failed to allocate new recrd");
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

int main() {

  static const char *tomatoes = "tomatoes 10Kg CHF 55";
  static const char *carrots = "carrots 15Kg CHF 40";
  static const char *peppers = "peppers 2Kg CHF 6";

  struct s_table *t = s_table_new();
  assert(t);
  s_table_delete(t);
  struct s_table *t2 = s_table_new();
  assert(t2);
  t = s_table_new();
  assert(t);
  s_table_delete(t2);
  s_table_add_record(t, carrots, carrots + strlen(carrots));
  printf("First record added\n");
  s_table_add_record(t, carrots, carrots + strlen(carrots));
  printf("Second record added \n");
  s_table_add_record(t, carrots, carrots + strlen(carrots));
  s_table_add_record(t, carrots, carrots + strlen(carrots));
  s_table_add_record(t, peppers, peppers + strlen(peppers));
  s_table_add_record(t, tomatoes, tomatoes + strlen(tomatoes));
  printf("All records added \n");
  s_table_remove_record(t, peppers, peppers + strlen(peppers));

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(t));` should be `malloc(sizeof(struct s_table));`. Also, you haven't shown us the definition of `s_table_delete`

Comment: There are many errors in the code, but the main reason why the flow doesn't enter the loop is that: 1) you don't put anything into `t->records->next` (check your `s_table_add_record` function) and 2) the for loop condition checks for `t->records->next` which is empty.

Comment: Yes, that's surely one of the main problems, I need to assign something into t->record->next when I add a new records. Thanks.

Comment: the delete method is:  void s_table_delete(struct s_table *t) { free(t); }

Comment: @bugs_and_stars then your delete will leak memory. You do two mallocs but only one free.

Comment: also true; I should add free(t->records); thanks

Comment: Trying to program in C without knowing how to use a debugger is a terrible idea. If you single step through your code with a debugger, you will find a lot of the bugs quickly.

Comment: It's not your immediate problem, but do you understand what `t->records = t->records->next` does?

Comment: Yes  user253751, it moves me to the next element in the records linked list: if I am at element 2, I go to element 3. It is like writing i++.